# Noticing the tab was discarded by Chrome on next open

Tags: javascript, google-chrome

Chrome, by default, discards unused tabs on the background in order to save memory.

I'd like to know if there's a way so I could now if my website was discarded by Chrome - so I could tell my user, next time they go in, instructions on how to avoid that happening (by going to chrome://discards)

Sure, it's not hard to know if my website was closed, but **is there any way to be sure it was Chrome saving memory?**

Comment: I mean this: https://developers.google.com/web/updates/2015/09/tab-discarding Sorry if I expressed myself confusingly.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**2019 update:**
In Chrome 68+ you can check for the `document.wasDiscarded` property.
Source: https://developers.google.com/web/updates/2018/07/page-lifecycle-api